# Stop routine Service start from bringing an existing background process to foreground

Tags: android, service

I have an app with a service that polls at set intervals using the AlarmManager, and when the main app activity is active on screen. The issue I have is, if the app's process is in the background (has not been killed) and the service begins to poll, it brings the main app activity to the foreground.

How do I stop this from happening? Essentially, I want all of the app's processes to remain in the background, unless the user chooses otherwise.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us some of the relevant code? What PendingIntent is the AlarmManager sending, and what does the target of that intent do?

Comment: The pending intent uses getService and the target class is the Service's class. If I kill the apps task, the service starts and processes in the background as expected. If the apps task is a background task, then it gets brought to the foreground by the intent that starts the service. I can post code later when I'm at my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue I have is, if the app's process is in the background (has not been killed) and the service begins to poll, it brings the main app activity to the foreground.

Then you are calling `startActivity()`, or *possibly* `startForeground()` (I'm not aware that `startForeground()` would push an existing task to the foreground, but I haven't tried it and cannot rule it out).

Comment: Good call. I call startActivity sometimes depending on another variable that is hidden away in code I hadn't looked at in a while. Seeing your answer just made me remember! Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @confused_at_times: Prevent what from happening? If you don't want to call `startActivity()`, don't call `startActivity()`.

Comment: The activity I am starting, which calls finish on itself is not the activity that I see on screen. What I see is the last activity window before the app is sent to the background. I can get around this by changing the called activity to a service so startActivity is never called.